# Python - Replacing Indice Values in Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a nested list like:

`nest = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]`

I want to replace all the values from a specified range in each nested list to 1, from x to y.

If `x` is the starting point and `y` is the ending point, and for example `x = 1` and `y = 3`, I would like the following to end up with...

`nest = [[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0]]`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: To avoid attracting down-votes consider posting a code attempt with your question.

Comment: That is a question, and all my code attempts were wrong, so why post them?

Comment: There is no question mark anywhere in your "question".  If you post code we can explain why it's wrong.  As it is, it looks like you are asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I thought it was obvious that I was asking how to achieve the example, I will make sure to put in a question mark next time. In this case, my code wouldn't have helped anything so I opted to lay out the problem in as simple terms as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
nest = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
x = 1
y = 3
for array in nest:
    for i in range(x, y+1):
        array[i] = 1

print(nest)
```

I think you would benefit from a basic Python tutorial too, for example try codecademy.com.

Comment: Or replace the inner loop with a slice `arr[x:y+1] = [1]*(y-x+1)`, which is about 20% faster in this example.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was looking for, thanks. Ive gone through more than a few basic tuts, is this called anything special so I can practce it?

Comment: @JonnyDoeInWisco I would recommend looking specifically at lists and iteration (what this problem involved). Ability comes with experience and practice, try giving yourself tasks to complete and tackling them yourself and searching things up when necessary; that's mainly how I learned.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using slicing.

```
ones = [1]  * (y - x + 1)
for seq in nest:
    seq[x:y+1] = ones
```